# How to let user move an image into div to make a preview

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

i have

```
<div id="logo" style="border: 3px coral solid;position:absolute;left:160px;top:35px;width:140px; height:100px; z-index:5">
   <img src="img.png" ></img>
</div>
```

img.png is bigger then div dimension so it will be shown outside div.
i have to show just a piece of image inside that div, so in x from 0 to 140px and in y from 0 to 100px. and i have to let user move image to center only the part that him want. can you help me? can i use some jquery script to do this?

Comment: This will get you started I think. I don't feel like figuring it out for you though =). http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

Comment: is what i want! thanks! and to have img inside div shown only inside div and not outside? what can i do?

Comment: overflow:hidden on the container should clip any part of the image outside the container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED USING jqueryui.com/demos/draggable